# Application of approximation of moments on poisson distribution

Tags: statistics, approximation, moment-generating-functions, expected-value

Exercises 101 in Chapter 4 Of the book "Mathematical Statistics and Data Analysis" by Rica states:

> Find the approximate mean and variance of Y = √ X, where X is a random
>   variable following a Poisson distribution.

Here is my attempted solution:

$Y=g(x)=\sqrt{x}$; $ f(x)= e^{-\lambda} \frac{\lambda ^x}{x!}$ where $\mu_x=E[X]=\lambda$ And  $\sigma^2_X=Var[X]=\lambda$

I applied the delta method for approximate moments, which states:

$$ \mu_y \approx g(\mu) + \frac{1}{2} \sigma^2_X g``(\mu) = \sqrt{\lambda} + \frac12 \lambda \times(-\frac14 \lambda ^\frac{-3}{2}) = \sqrt{\lambda}-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{\lambda}}$$

$$ \sigma_Y^2 \approx \sigma_X^2[g`(\mu)]^2$$

**Is this correct?**

Also, in the scripts from my course is that it holds that

$$ Ps(\alpha) \approx N(\alpha,\alpha)$$

I was wondering if this could also be applied in the context of delta method, such as:

$Y=g(x)=\sqrt{x}$; $ f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\lambda}exp{(-\frac{1}{2\lambda^2}\times(x-\lambda)^2})$ where $\mu_x=E[X]=\lambda$ And  $\sigma^2_X=Var[X]=\lambda$

Comment: see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1536459/expected-value-of-square-root-of-poisson-random-variable  Note that if you have the expectation you can get the variance readily, $\text{Var}(X^\frac12) = E(X) - E(X^\frac12)^2$, so it may not be necessary to use a Taylor expansion there.

Comment: Reality check using simulation. Let $\lambda = 4.$ Simulate a million values of X ~ POIS(4) and see what happens. In R, `x = rpois(10^6, 4);  mean(x);  sd(x); mean(sqrt(x))` returns  4.001432, 1.998077, and 1.922534. From a million iterations you can expect about two-place accuracy. Are the answers what you expect?