# Calculate EZ and Var(Z) where $Z=e^{(X+Y)^2}$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

X,Y are independent random variables with normal distribution, their expected value is equal to 0 and variance to 1/8. Calculate the expected value and variance of $Z=e^{(X+Y)^2}$

My approach $EX^2,EY^2$=1/8, since variance is equal to 1/8 and $EX=0$, $EXY=0$, then $E(X+Y)^2$=1/4 and here is my question, is it true that $Ee^{(X+Y)^2}$=$e^{E(X+Y)^2}$?

If so, why? If not, how do I get this done? And can this be broaden to the general f(X)?

Comment: No!  $\mathbb{E}[\exp(T)]\neq \exp(\mathbb{E}T)$ unless the real-valued random variable $T$ is constant a.s.

Comment: Try the $n$-th moments $E[X^r]$, which has closed-form expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general,  $E[g(X)]\ne g (E[X])$ (the equality holds if $g()$ is linear - or if the random variable is actually a constant).

I can think of two ways of attacking this.

First, express (if you can) $g(x)$ as a Taylor series (perhaps around the mean), then compute $E[g(X)]$ as an infinite sum involving the derivatives of $g()$ and the (centered) moments of $X$ ([example](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1536459/expected-value-of-square-root-of-poisson-random-variable/1537267#1537267)).

Second, compute it directly.

I'd go for the second one here, because $g()$ looks related to the density.

First, a simplification: notice that $W=X+Y$ is normal $N(0,1/4)$ : $f_W(w)=\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}} \exp(-2 w^2)$

Then

$$E[Z]=E[e^{W^2}]= \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\int e^{w^2} e^{-2 w^2} dw$$

Can you go on from here?