# Evaluate $E\left[N\left(\frac {N-1} {N}\right)^N\right]$, where $N \sim \text{Poisson}(10)$.

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution

> Suppose you are given a random number, $N$, of balls together with the same random number $N$ of urns, where $N$ has a Poisson distribution with parameter 10. Assume each ball is equally likely to go into any of the urns, $1, 2, ..., N$. It is further assumed that the balls are put into the urns independently. Find the expected number of urns that are empty after all balls have been put into the urns.

**Attempt**

Define random variables $I_k$ for $k = 1, 2, ... N$, such that

$$
I_k =
\begin{cases}
1, & \text{if the k-th urn is empty} \\
0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

Now, consider for $k=1, ... , N$, we have

\begin{align*}
E[I_k | N = n] &= P(\{\text{no balls go into k-th urn}\}) \\
&= \left(\frac {n-1} {n}\right)^n
\end{align*}

Hence

\begin{align*}
E\left[\sum_{k=1}^n I_k | N = n\right] &= \sum_{k=1}^nE[I_k | N = n] \\
&= n\left(\frac {n-1} {n}\right)^n
\end{align*}

Define the random variable $E\left[\sum_{k=1}^n I_k | N\right] = E\left[\sum_{k=1}^n I_k | N = n\right]$, $N = n$ for some $n \in \mathbf{R}$. Then apply the law of iterated expectations and we get

\begin{align*}
E\left[\sum_{k=1}^N I_k \right] &= E\left[E\left[\sum_{k=1}^n I_k | N\right]\right] \\
&= E\left[N\left(\frac {N-1} {N}\right)^N\right] \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} k\left(\frac {k-1} {k}\right)^k e^{-10} \frac {10^k} {k!}
\end{align*}

From here, I face some difficulty evaluating the final expression. Also, I am not entirely sure if my approach is correct in general.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It's important to note that your sum isn't defined when $N=0$ which occurs with non zero probability. How should we interpret this event? Wolfram doesn't produce a closed form of this sum, FYI, but your approach seems legit

Comment: Yup, that makes sense! Must have overlooked it, thanks for the feedback! Should have defined the bounds for $N \ge 1$, as it naturally should be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is fine, though the sum should begin at $k=1$ (or $k=2$).

I don't think the expression has a nice closed form.

Noticing that the mean of the variable is $\lambda = 10$, and that the approximation $(1-1/n)^n \approx e^{-1}$ should work reasonably around $n\approx 10$, then the function $g(n)= n \, (1-1/n)^n$ is approximately linear around the mean.

Then we can approximate $$E[g(n)] \approx g(E[n]) = g(\lambda) = 10 \, (1-1/10)^{10} = 3.48678\dots \tag 1$$

If we really wish, we could refine this by computing the second derivate of $g()$, [see eg](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1536459/expected-value-of-square-root-of-poisson-random-variable/1537267#1537267). This gives $3.48589\dots$ , which already suggests that the approximation $(1)$ is good.

Further, one can check that $g(n)$ is concave, hence (by [Jensen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality)) $(1)$ is also an upper bound.