# Expected value of $\exp\big(-\frac{1}{X+1}\big)$ when X have binomial distribution

Tags: probability, random-variables, expected-value, approximation, binomial-distribution

I have a function $f(X)= e^{-\frac{1}{X+1}}$ where X is $\operatorname{Bin}(n,p)$.

Is there a way to simplify $E[f(X)]=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\left(\begin{array}{l}
n \\
k
\end{array}\right) p^{k}(1-p)^{n-k} e^{-\frac{1}{k+1}}$.

If not, is there a good approximation when $p<<1, n>100$.

Comment: Use  Moment generating function

Comment: for large n you can get good approximation with normal distribution approximating binomial.

Comment: @Eudoxus , I don't see how it can help since the exponent is $1/x$ and not $x$. Am I missing something?

Comment: This is simply a Bernstein polynomial of degree $n$ with Bernstein coefficients $exp(-1/(k+1))$.

Comment: Being a Bernstein polynomial,my comment doesn’t apply and check out this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernstein_polynomial. I don’t think thier is a nice way to clean it up. An approximation would work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I highly doubt that that can be simplified. An approximation can be obtained by doing a [Taylor expansion around the mean](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1536459/expected-value-of-square-root-of-poisson-random-variable/1537267#1537267).

The second order approximation I get is

$$ E[f(X)] \approx f(\mu) + \frac12f''(\mu) \sigma^2
=\exp\left(- \frac{1}{1+\mu}\right)\left(1-  \sigma^2 \frac{\mu + \frac12}{(1+\mu)^4}\right)$$

where $\mu = np$ , $\sigma^2=np(1-p)$

Some values for $n=100$

```
    p        exact   approx
   0.1      0.90623  0.90721
   0.05     0.82528  0.82942
   0.01     0.55403  0.55024
```

We could add more terms to the expansion. It's not clear, though, under which conditions this behaves as an asymptotic expansion (so that higher order terms can be neglected). For fixed (and small) $p$, the second term (and, one hopes, the next ones) turns negligible for $n\gg 1/p$.

Furthermore, because $f(X)$ is concave, [Jensen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality)  gives us the strict bound  $E[f(X)] < \exp\left(- \frac{1}{1+\mu}\right)$

Comment: Perfect. I never thought of using a Taylor expansion.

Comment: @leonboy, thanks for the answer.